# How to add views in UIScrollview and then add constraints using storyboard iOS objC

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am creating UI like below image.
[image]

I kept one view at bottom and one view at top using storyboard and constraints.
Now between these two views there is some are which I want to scroll.
I have added some labels , buttons to it and added constraints. Up to this,it works perfect (Only middle portion of screen is only scrolling).
But I am having 600 * 600 area(using width any, height any -sizes class) in which top view has fixed height constraint 80 and bottom view having fixed height 100.
My problem is , there some more labels and buttons to be added in same scrollview below existing ones. 
How do I place more views in storyboard iOS objC

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know exact solution,but I have tried something like this. So my answer could help some one else

1: Make a UIView subclass that will contain all the buttons you could ever want.

2: Make a XIB for it, NOT in the Storyboard. Add the buttons to a blank, resizable UIView and link them up.

3: When UIViewController WITH the UIScrollView loads. init the subclassed UIView using initWithNibNamed...

4: Add it as a subView of the UIScrollView and set scrollView.contentSize

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a UITableView with a bunch of UITableViewCell members.  It automatically sets up the scroll behavior that you are looking for.  Based on the index of the UITableViewCell you can present whatever data that you want to in the cell.

Comment: Table view is not useful  in my case as middle view is not simple view ...Thats why I have only option to use scrollview